# iOS [undefinedquery] failure. state: 404, response: The server was unable to process the request from the application. Please try again later

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst

MobileFirst Environment 6.3
XCode Version 6.4

I have a Hybrid App and I am getting a 404 error when invoking an adapter when testing my iPad environment on XCode (all works fine when testing the common resources). Here are the XCode console logs:

```
2015-07-29 09:36:55.679 MyApplication[31753:78214] [DEBUG] [WL_SPLASH] -[WLSplashView updateImage] in WLSplashView.m:194 :: Splash screen image is Default
2015-07-29 09:36:55.746 MyApplication[31753:78214] [DEBUG] [WL_SPLASH] -[WLSplashView updateImage] in WLSplashView.m:194 :: Splash screen image is Default
2015-07-29 09:36:55.761 MyApplication[31753:78419] [DEBUG] [WL_CONFIG] -[WLConfig init] in WLConfig.m:68 :: {
"application id" = MyApp;
"application version" = "1.0";
authenticitySharedData = "${authenticitySharedData}";
buildtime = 1438176990;
environment = ipad;
host = "1.1.1.1";
ignoredFileExtensions = "";
platformVersion = "6.3.0.0";
port = PORT;
protocol = http;
testWebResourcesChecksum = false;
wlAppFamily = "";
wlMainFile = "index.html";
wlSecureDirectUpdatePublicKey = "";
wlServerContext = "/MobileFirstMyApp/";
wlShareCookies = "";
wlShareUserCert = false;
wlUid = "GpcFvRuPrj0ZAvmmAFHPyw==";
}
2015-07-29 09:36:55.773 MyApplication[31753:78214] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UIViewController: 0x7a8b3610>.
2015-07-29 09:36:55.795 MyApplication[31753:78419] [DEBUG] [WL_INIT] -[WLImpl isFirstLaunchAfterInstallOrUpgrade] in WLImpl.m:236 :: isFirstLaunchAfterInstallOrUpgrade: isEncryptedWebResources - 0
2015-07-29 09:36:55.806 MyApplication[31753:78419] [DEBUG] [WL_INIT] -[WLImpl isFirstLaunchAfterInstallOrUpgrade] in WLImpl.m:237 :: isFirstLaunchAfterInstallOrUpgrade: isDirectUpdatePerformed - 0
2015-07-29 09:36:55.819 MyApplication[31753:78419] [DEBUG] [WL_INIT] -[WLImpl isFirstLaunchAfterInstallOrUpgrade] in WLImpl.m:246 :: isFirstLaunchAfterInstallOrUpgrade: there is no encrypted web resources or direct update.
2015-07-29 09:36:55.832 MyApplication[31753:78419] [DEBUG] [WL_INIT] -[WLImpl initWL] in WLImpl.m:123 :: handleAppWebResources: At first launch
2015-07-29 09:36:55.884 MyApplication[31753:78419] [DEBUG] [WL_INIT] -[WLImpl initWL] in WLImpl.m:147 :: handleAppWebResources: encrypted web resources should not be extracted
2015-07-29 09:36:56.899 MyApplication[31753:78214] Apache Cordova native platform version 3.6.1 is starting.
2015-07-29 09:36:56.899 MyApplication[31753:78214] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2015-07-29 09:36:56.967 MyApplication[31753:78214] Unlimited access to network resources
2015-07-29 09:36:56.983 MyApplication[31753:78214] [DEBUG] [WL_INIT] +[WLImpl wwwFolderName] in WLImpl.m:582 :: WLCordovaAppDelegate:wwwFolderName: //Folder/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/EB8E276D-1916-444C-BF41-D2B91B524BD8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/84E0A7BB-C728-4928-8458-619487D7BB80/MyApplication.app/www
2015-07-29 09:36:57.086 MyApplication[31753:78214] [CDVTimer][wlapp] 3.044009ms
2015-07-29 09:36:57.087 MyApplication[31753:78214] [CDVTimer][push] 0.452995ms
2015-07-29 09:36:57.087 MyApplication[31753:78214] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 3.947020ms
2015-07-29 09:36:57.106 MyApplication[31753:78214] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2015-07-29 09:36:58.443 MyApplication[31753:78214] Finished load of: file:folder/index.html
2015-07-29 09:36:58.446 MyApplication[31753:78214] [DEBUG] [WL_INIT] +[WLImpl wwwFolderName] in WLImpl.m:582 :: WLCordovaAppDelegate:wwwFolderName: folder
2015-07-29 09:36:58.679 MyApplication[31753:78214] THREAD WARNING: ['NetworkStatus'] took '28.627197' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
2015-07-29 09:36:59.991 MyApplication[31753:78396] [DEBUG] [NONE] establishSSLClientAuth
2015-07-29 09:37:00.004 MyApplication[31753:78463] [DEBUG] [NONE] ondeviceready event dispatched
2015-07-29 09:37:00.010 MyApplication[31753:78214] THREAD WARNING: ['WLApp'] took '17.805176' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
2015-07-29 09:37:00.017 MyApplication[31753:78214] [WARN] [USER_CERT_AUTH] +[WLUserAuthManager getCertificateIdentifier] in WLUserAuthManager.m:68 :: Certificate Identifier Key: com.worklight.userenrollment.certificate:com.MyApp
2015-07-29 09:37:00.030 MyApplication[31753:78214] THREAD WARNING: ['UserAuth'] took '16.427979' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
2015-07-29 09:37:00.047 MyApplication[31753:78214] log1
2015-07-29 09:37:00.049 MyApplication[31753:78463] [DEBUG] [NONE] wlclient init started
2015-07-29 09:37:00.068 MyApplication[31753:78214] THREAD WARNING: ['Globalization'] took '20.590820' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
2015-07-29 09:37:00.092 MyApplication[31753:78394] [DEBUG] [NONE] CookieMgr read cookies: {}
2015-07-29 09:37:00.104 MyApplication[31753:78396] [DEBUG] [NONE] Read cookies: null
2015-07-29 09:37:00.106 MyApplication[31753:78214] THREAD WARNING: ['DeviceAuth'] took '35.353760' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
2015-07-29 09:37:00.107 MyApplication[31753:78395] [DEBUG] [NONE] establishSSLClientAuth isCertificateExists:  false
2015-07-29 09:37:00.118 MyApplication[31753:78397] [DEBUG] [NONE] Request [undefinedquery]
2015-07-29 09:37:00.132 MyApplication[31753:78493] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPCLIENTWRAPPER_PACKAGE] +[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper requestWithURL:] in WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:37 :: Request url is http://1.1.1.1:PORT/MobileFirstMyAppundefinedquery
2015-07-29 09:37:00.134 MyApplication[31753:78485] [DEBUG] [NONE] before: initOptions.onSuccess
2015-07-29 09:37:00.139 MyApplication[31753:78489] [DEBUG] [NONE] after: initOptions.onSuccess
2015-07-29 09:37:00.147 MyApplication[31753:78487] [DEBUG] [NONE] added onPause and onResume event handlers
2015-07-29 09:37:00.151 MyApplication[31753:78490] [DEBUG] [NONE] wlclient init success
2015-07-29 09:37:00.164 MyApplication[31753:78493] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPCLIENTWRAPPER_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper start] in WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:182 :: Starting the request with URL http://1.1.1.1:PORT/MobileFirstMyAppundefinedquery
2015-07-29 09:37:00.222 MyApplication[31753:78214] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPCLIENTWRAPPER_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:209 :: Request Failed
2015-07-29 09:37:00.229 MyApplication[31753:78214] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPCLIENTWRAPPER_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:210 :: Response Status Code : 404
2015-07-29 09:37:00.236 MyApplication[31753:78214] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPCLIENTWRAPPER_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:211 :: Response Error : Expected status code in (200-299), got 404
2015-07-29 09:37:00.410 MyApplication[31753:78396] [ERROR] [NONE] [undefinedquery] failure. state: 404, response: The server was unable to process the request from the application. Please try again later.
```

I think that issue stems from a the query path not being set properly (reads undefinedquery). I deleted and re-added the "iPad" environment from the application-descriptor to which I did not change any properties. I ran the environment in Xcode and I am still getting an error.

My code is below. It is pretty straight forward. One other thing that it could be is that I am trying out the MobileFirst authentication (AdapterAuthentication) for the first time. I think that I have it set up correctly (again works fine from common) but one thing that I am doubting myself on is that I followed the Hybrid example for setting up the ChallengeHandler. I was hoping to just use the Hybrid authentication method for all environments but, for an iPad environment, do I have to create the ChallengeHandler in the native IOS code? If so, I may have just missed this in the documentation.

```
init = function () {

    var invocationData = {
        adapter: 'MyAdapter',
        procedure: 'myProcedure'
    };

    WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, {
        onSuccess: doSuccess,
        onFailure: doFailure //Goes Here
    });    
}

MyChallengeHandler = WL.Client.createChallengeHandler("MyAuthRealm");

MyChallengeHandler.isCustomResponse = function (response) {
    if (!response || !response.responseJSON || response.responseText === null) {
        return false;
    }

    if (typeof (response.responseJSON.authRequired) !== 'undefined') {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};

MyChallengeHandler.handleChallenge = function (response) {
    var authRequired = response.responseJSON.authRequired;

    if (authRequired == true) {
        popLoginWindow();
    } else if (authRequired == false) {

       cleanupLoginWindow();
       MyChallengeHandler.submitSuccess();

    }
};
```

Comment: If you created a Hybrid app you only need in most cases to implement in the challenge handler code in the common folder; that's fine. which tutorial did you follow? Did you try the sample application? what's Xcode 8.4?

Comment: @IdanAdar Thanks for the clarification. I meant to say Xcode 6.4 (iOS SDK 8.4). I am using this [tutorial](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/authentication-security/adapter-based-authentication/adapter-based-authentication-hybrid-applications/). The sample app does work properly.

Comment: @IdanAdar In the logs for the sample app I noticed this: `2015-07-29 10:57:23.836 SingleStepAuth[45682:133504] [DEBUG] [NONE] establishSSLClientAuth isCertificateExists:  false
2015-07-29 10:57:23.845 SingleStepAuth[45682:133500] [DEBUG] [NONE] Request [/apps/services/api/SingleStepAuth/ipad/query]` where in my app I get `Request [undefinedquery]`. Where is this assignment coming from?

Comment: Your implementation is not like the sample. Can you upload the file where this code resides? Additionally, why is there a ‘ char instead of ' char surrounding the adapter and procedure names?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Idan for your assistance. I was able to solve my own issue. So the adapter was being called immediately on load and as it turns out, it looks like the Adapter was being called before Worklight finished all of its initialization. I added a 500 ms delayed task to the init call and the adapter was called successfully. (not sure why this was not a problem in the common resource)

However, while this does solve the issue, I was wondering if there was a better way to determine as to whether the WL initialization process finished. Let me know if there is a better solution and I will update my answer.

## Update

As per Idan's solution below, placing the initialization inside wlCommonInit() fixed the issue.

Comment: You should implement your flow like in the sample. Your code must start inside wlCommonInit() in main.js.